# How decrypt file which was encrypted by windows 7

Tags: windows-7, security, encryption, decryption

My User profile was deleted and newly added by me on today. I didn't delete user files and copied to new user profiles. but i can't open many of files. file name is green color. Therefore file should be encrypted. I can't find any security certificate on this machine and  When  try to remove encryption from right click menu, it ask administrator privileges, I try to do using domain and local admin account but result is same as all the times. please help me if you have understand about my problem.

Comment: You deleted the profile and when you did that you deleted the certificate.  If you have no backup of that certificate then your files will remain encrypted without any way of decrypting them.  The only solution to this problem is to have the certificate that you deleted and it's to late for that since it's deleted

Comment: no i deleted only registry. profile renamed.all files are available. how can i find certificate?

Comment: If you cannot log into the original profile it **cannot** be retrieved.  Restore your files from your backup.  There is not another solution to your problem

Comment: Ok, i will try. do you know anyway to restore registry?

Comment: Your chance of recovering something deleted from drive decreases sharply with every action you take on the computer after the deletion. (As disk space gets reused.) After a couple of minutes, those chances reach "miniscule". (That is why the first thing after "oh sh** I deleted vital data on a machine without backups" is to pull the plug -- yes, pull the plug, don't shut down -- and get a LiveCD or boot from some other medium, only accessing the drive in question in read-only mode until you recovered the data.) Your best bet is to restore from backup. You *have* a backup, don't you?

Comment: @RuwanPradeep The registry cannot be recovered since you didn't create a backup of what you deleted in the registry.

Comment: I have no backups. that is a big issue that i faced

Comment: We call that "learning through pain".

Comment: Yes, but problem is no one knows how this is encrypted? that is big problem i have

Comment: @RuwanPradeep - We all know how it was encrypted (Windows EFS), it was encrypted with the profile's certificate (which when EFS was enabled you were told to backup), but you don't have that certificate because you didn't export and backup the certificate, before you made the original profile inaccessible.

Comment: You say that you’ve tried “local admin account”, but have you tried ***the*** local `Administrator` account?

Comment: @scott i used both local and domain admin account

Comment: You’re not answering my question.  Did you use ***a*** local account that has administrative privileges because it is in the Administrator **s** group, or did you use ***the***  builtin, hidden account *whose name is literally* ``Administrator``?

Comment: @scott No i used local admin account which was created by me previously. I didn't use hidden administrator account.

Comment: You might want to try it.  You can find information on unhiding and enabling the hidden ```Administrator``` account on this site (and elsewhere on the web).

Comment: i replaced app data file from  old profile. now i can open file